# Update ListView from ListTile or deleting tile from list

Tags: flutter

I write a simple application for the entry and exit of cars to the warehouse.
Faced a problem. I get the machines from a separate database, the application displays their list (ListView.separated). Then the guard selects the car, checks the car data in it, takes a photo and a photo is sent to the database. And at this point, I need to update the list of machines in ListView.
How can I do this from ListTile?

Screen code listing below.

car_list_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:storage_security/car_tile.dart';
import 'package:storage_security/cars_repository.dart';
import 'package:storage_security/theme.dart';
import 'car.dart';

class CarsListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CarsListScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CarsListScreenState();
}

class _CarsListScreenState extends State<CarsListScreen> {
  List<Car>? _carsList;
  bool carsFromStorage = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadCarsList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(carsFromStorage ? 'OUT' : 'IN'),),
      body: (_carsList == null)
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : _carsList!.isEmpty ? const Center(child: Text('No data')) :
            ListView.separated(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
              itemCount: _carsList!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                return CarTile(car: _carsList![i]);
          },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: darkTheme.appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            IconButton(onPressed: (){
                carsFromStorage = false;
                _loadCarsList();
              }, icon: Image.asset('assets/images/green_arrow.png'), iconSize: 48,),
            IconButton(onPressed: (){
                carsFromStorage = true;
                _loadCarsList();
             }, icon: Image.asset('assets/images/red_arrow.png'), iconSize: 48,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void>? _loadCarsList() async {
    _carsList = null; // for CircularProgressIndicator
    setState(() {});

    _carsList = await CarsRepository().getCarList(carsFromStorage);
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

car_tile.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'car.dart';

class CarTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const CarTile({
    super.key,
    required this.car,
  });

  final Car car;
  final toEvent = const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/event.png'));
  final toStorage = const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/storage.png'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return ListTile(
        leading: car.isShipment ? toEvent : toStorage,
        title: Text(car.car, style: theme.textTheme.bodyMedium),
        subtitle: Text(car.driver, style: theme.textTheme.labelSmall,),
        trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
        onTap: () async {
          final result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            '/car',
            arguments: car,
          );

          if (result == true) {
            // >>>>> RELOAD CARS LIST OR DELETE THIS TILE FROM LIST <<<<<
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

In fact, I need to call the _loadCarsList function in car_list_screen.dart from the >>>>> RELOAD CARS LIST OR DELETE THIS TILE FROM LIST <<<<< in car_tile.dart or deleting this tile from list.

Sorry for my english, I'm not English-speaking.

I tried to google this problem, but I found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `VoidCallback onCarListUpdated` to your `CarTile` :

```
 class CarTile extends StatelessWidget {
    const CarTile({
      super.key,
      required this.car,
      required this.onCarListUpdated,
    });

  final Car car;
  final toEvent = const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/event.png'));
  final toStorage = const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/storage.png'));
  final VoidCallback onCarListUpdated;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final theme = Theme.of(context);
  return ListTile(
    leading: car.isShipment ? toEvent : toStorage,
    title: Text(car.car, style: theme.textTheme.bodyMedium),
    subtitle: Text(car.driver, style: theme.textTheme.labelSmall,),
    trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
    onTap: () async {
      final result = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
        '/car',
        arguments: car,
      );

      if (result == true) {
        // >>>>> RELOAD CARS LIST OR DELETE THIS TILE FROM LIST <<<<<
        onCarListUpdated.call();
      }
     }
   );
 }
}
```

And pass `_loadCarsList` as an argument in itemBuilder inside `_CarsListScreenState` class:

```
itemBuilder: (context, i) {
  return CarTile(
    car: _carsList![i],
    onCarListUpdated: _loadCarsList,
  );
},
```

Comment: It works! You're my hero :)
Thank you very much!